# distribution of the difference of discrete uniform RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $P_1, P_2$ be independent discrete uniform random variables on $\{0,1,...,k\}$.  Suppose we want to compute  $$\mathbb{P}(P_1 > P_2).$$
Is the best approach to see $\mathbb{P}(P_1 > P_2) = \mathbb{P}(P_1-P_2>0)$ and then find the distribution of $P_1-P_2$ to finish it out? If so, how would one do this? If not, what would be the other better way of doing it?  Another method I considered is letting $P_{2}' = -P_2$ and then $\mathbb{P}(P_1 > P_2) = \mathbb{P}(P_1+P_{2}'>0)$.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, $P(P_1 \gt P_2) = P(P_2 \gt P_1)$. It's easy to see that $P(P_1 = P_2) = \frac{1}{k+1}$. So,

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 &=& 2P(P_1 \gt P_2) + P(P_1 = P_2). \\
&& \\
\therefore P(P_1 \gt P_2) &=& \dfrac{1-P(P_1 = P_2)}{2} \\
&=&\dfrac{k}{2(k+1)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Wouldn't it be the case that $$\mathbb{P}(P_1 = P_2) = \mathbb{P}(P_1 = n)\mathbb{P}(P_2 = n) = \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$$
for any $n \in \{0,1,...,k\}$?

Comment: Ignore that, summing on $n$ from $0$ to $k$ yields $\mathbb{P}(P_1=P_2)=\frac{1}{k+1}$, as you said.

Comment: Yes, that's right.